# php - if statement with more factors

Tags: php

I am trying to make this IF statement to work:

```
" . ($currentpage == '/adver.php' ? 'active' : '' || $currentpage == 'editad.php' ? 'active' : '' ) . "
```

What I want to do, is that if the `$currentpage` is `/adver.php` or `/editad.php`, then "active" should be printed out.

The above doesn't work. How can I make the IF statement to function correct?

Comment: Please do NOT abuse the ternary like that. You're probably running into all kinds of bad results because `||` has a higher precedence than `:` and `?`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you insist on using the `if` shorthand, you can try something like:

```
" . ($currentpage == '/adver.php' ? 'active' : ($currentpage == 'editad.php' ? 'active' : '')) . "
```

Alternatively, you could something like:

```
" . (in_array($currentpage, array('/adver.php', 'editad.php')) ? 'active' : '') . "
```

Comment: When I use the ternary php code you've suggested, the only thing that is outputted is "active". Just "active" written in plain text. The HTML codes gets disabled.

Answer (score 3):

Use `basename()` with `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` to get the current script file name and than compare

```
if(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == 'adver.php' || basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == 'editad.php') {
   echo 'class="active"'; //Whatever you want to echo
}
```

You can simply create a function(I often use) to get the script file name like

```
function script_name() {
   return basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
}
```

Now you can use something like

```
(script_name() == 'index.php') ? '' : '';
```

---

When I use this to `echo` out the active page I often use something like

```
function is_active($script_name) {
   if(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == $script_name) {
      return 'class="active"';
   }
}
```

Now you can simply use the above function say in your menu like

```
<a href="index.php" <?php echo is_active('index.php'); ?>>
```

Comment: I think this is a more elegant way to write it :)

Comment: Were you negative voted? Damn, this is such an elegant solution! I'll upvote you, as these solutions should be the ones being used.

Comment: @Sikian thank you for your sportsmanship, I don't know whether is THE elegant way, but I just contributed a decent solution...

Comment: Yes, this is perhaps more elegant. I'd recommend adding the `active` part in your question :-)

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're using the *ternary operator* incorrectly.

You may want to try the following code:

```
($currentpage == '/adver.php' || $currentpage == 'editad.php') ? 'active' : ''
```

Remember that the syntax of the ternary operator is the following:

```
(comparison) ? (if true) : (if false)
```

Therefore, the full comparison should go at the beginning. Anyway, consider using a normal if/else when possible, as ternary operators might be confusing both for the writer and the reader (and furthermore, you don't really need the else in this case).

EDIT: I recommend using Mr. Alien's solution.

Comment: When I use the ternary php code you've suggested, the only thing that is outputted is "active". Just "active" written in plain text. The HTML codes gets disabled.

Answer (score 1):

```
if($currentpage == "adver.php" || $currentpage == "editad.php") {
    echo "Active";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake to use '(' and ')'

Your should use like this

```
" . ($currentpage == '/adver.php') ? 'active' : '' || ($currentpage == 'editad.php') ? 'active' : ''  . "
```

instead of

```
" . ($currentpage == '/adver.php' ? 'active' : '' || $currentpage == 'editad.php' ? 'active' : '')  . "
```